# Real chance percentage of 'Chance on ...' affix in legendaries?

Tags: diablo-iii

I wonder what the mathematical percentage of 'Chance on ...' affix on some legendary items.

For example, 
[Bovine Bardiche](https://us.diablo3.com/en/item/bovine-bardiche-Unique_Polearm_101_x1)
or 
[Sanguinary vambraces](https://us.diablo3.com/en/item/sanguinary-vambraces-Unique_Bracer_105_x1).

Comment: fwiw sangs are broken right now, they don't proc at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proc chance differs from item to item, and to come up with any number you need to run tests for specific items. 'Chance to ..' doesn't always mean 'Chance on every hit' as some effects have internal cooldowns.

For **Bovine Bardiche** there is some info in [wiki](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Bovine_Bardiche):

> The effect seems to have a 45 seconds cooldown, but the chance to summon is 100%.

For **Sanguinary Vambraces** I've managed to find [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo3Crusaders/comments/41xn28/why_doesnt_invoker_use_sanguinary_vambraces/):

> SV proc is quite low (5-10%)

and this [battle.net post](https://eu.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/10368899345):

> My trials resulted in ~10% chance to proc